# Bitmap Image manipulation in C++

Tags: c++, image, c++11, bitmap

I am inquiring as to how I would manipulate a bitmap image so that the image would rotate, and how to use the zoom functionality with the image.

I'm working on a fairly basic image viewer program, that goes through a windows window, and was wondering if anyone could help me on this one :)

Keep in mind my knowledge of higher c++ functions is fairly limited.

Comment: What's "higher C++ functions?". Also, as you're new to SO, something of note is that as it stands your question doesn't meet the site's requirements and may be closed. Read these for more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

> Keep in mind my knowledge of higher c++ functions is fairly limited.

The C++ Standard Library does not provide a graphics library.

You should at minimum specify the graphics library you are using. These transforms likely exist in the library you are using. Look there first.

These transforms can be expressed in mathematical form, but the best implementations can be quite complex because you would use these at varying rendering stages for the best looking results. Additionally, many algorithms exist -- each with time/quality/complexity tradeoffs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28bitmap%29

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Documentation.html), it could help you do most of the things you mentioned.